# Script not loaded in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My javascript class is loaded before the render of my page. So the `querySelectorAll` return `0`.

How to load my class after the Angular render ?

**page.ejs**

```
<body ng-app="GestiawebApp">
  <script src="myclass.js"></script>
  <!-- ng repeat <a href="#" data-dialog="true">....-->
</body>
```

**myclass.js**

```
+(function($) {

'use strict';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dialog="true"]');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var link = e.currentTarget,
          url = link.getAttribute('href'),
          messageText = link.getAttribute('data-dialog-message') || 'Êtes-vous sûr ?',
          btnClass = (link.getAttribute('data-dialog-danger')) ? 'is-danger' : 'is-main-color',
          actionTitle = link.getAttribute('data-dialog-action-title') || 'Valider',
          dialogNode, lightNode;

      lightNode = document.createElement('div');
      lightNode.classList.add('is-dark-light');
      document.body.appendChild(lightNode);

      $(lightNode).fadeIn();

      dialogNode = document.createElement('div');
      dialogNode.classList.add('dialog');
      document.body.appendChild(dialogNode);
      dialogNode.innerHTML = '<p>' + messageText + '</p><div class="space-20"></div><div class="flexline is-full has-margin no-mobile"><a class="btn" type="reset">Annuler</a><a data-loader="true" class="btn ' + btnClass + '" type="submit">' + actionTitle + '</a></div>';

      $(dialogNode).fadeIn();

      e.preventDefault();

      dialogNode.querySelector('[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.location.href = url;
      });

      dialogNode.querySelector('[type="reset"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
        $(lightNode).fadeOut( function() {
          lightNode.remove();
          $(dialogNode).fadeOut( function() {
            dialogNode.remove();
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });




});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are you using angularjs (1) or angular (2+)? Looks like angularjs

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.6.4.

Comment: @tonymx227 I edited my answer, you may find your answer given to your Angular version.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can add it to your assets (in the `angular.json` or `angular-cli.json` file), or if you can, import it from the `main.ts` file with other imports.

Then your script will be included globally to your app.

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "src/assets/scripts/myclass.js"
]
```

You can get more informations about global scripts in [the dedicated Angular GitHub doc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts).

**If you're using AngularJS:**

There is a similar post: [Load javascript files before angular.module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210800/load-javascript-files-before-angular-module) that deals with it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the js file in **assets** folder and then include in in **angular.json** in scripts array:

```
      "scripts": [
          "src/assets/gloveboxLibraries.min.js"
       ]
```